# How do I regex part of url

Tags: regex, pcre

I need help solving regex (PCRE). I want to extract the `hello-world` part from multiple url below. I got this so far:

```
^/news/(.*?)/$

https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-09/hello-world/topics/

https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-09/hello-world/gallery/

https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-09/hello-world/
```

But this captures `2017-08-09/hello-world/topics` and I only need `hello-world`

Comment: What is the rule here? Please formulate the requirements.

Comment: If I got it right and you want to find out which urls contain hello-world, why don't you just go with `hello-world` as pattern?

Comment: Is there a requirement preventing you from just doing `/hello-world/`?

Comment: Try the pattern `hello-world`. This returns `hello-world`.

Comment: To add things "hello-world" part always changes with the new articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in PCRE:

```
~/news/[^/]*/\K[^/]+~
```

- `/news/[^/]*/`: Match `/news/` followed by zero or more non-`/` followed by `/`
- `\K`: Forego matched information
- `[^/]+`: Match one or more non-`/` characters

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovfsS8/1)

---

You may also use a capturing group:

```
/news/[^/]*/([^/]+)
```

and extract capturing group #2

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ovfsS8/2)

Comment: where do I set the $ group?

Comment: What do you mean by `$` group? Just use `preg_match_all` to get the matches

Comment: I am trying to do this in nginx.conf

Comment: ok, then use: `/news/[^/]*/([^/]+)` as your regex and use `$1` for match

Answer (score 0):

IF hello-world represents an unknown text and the rest is fixed, try this:

```
^/news/2017-08-09/(.*?)/.*$
```

If date is not fixed, you can specify format it is in and use that instead, for example \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/(.*?)/
the group 1 has hello world

https://regex101.com/r/wFM7nc/1